# multidimensional object state in constructor

Tags: react-native

Happy New Year...

I am extremely new to RN and am building a small app to get a feel for it.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to clean this part up.

Below I have a <strike>nested</strike> multidimensional object `state` in the `constructor` and a `reset function`.

I have four `input` fields and a plain `text` area which I update dynamically based on a result.

Now whilst this works it feels not so clean, say if I wanted to add another <strike>nested</strike> multidimensional object `state` which sets different default values on `reset` I am going to have to add another `if block` to handle that so the it compounds the problem even further.

Any thoughts how to improve this or am I going about it the wrong way :/

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    input1: '',
    input2: '',
    input3: '',
    input4: '',
    result: {
      'ratio': 0,
      'style': '',
    },
  }
}

reset() {
  let newState = {};

  for (const field of Object.keys(this.state)) {
    if (field == 'result') {
      this.setState({
        result: {
          ratio: 0,
          style: '',
        }
      });

      continue;
    }

    newState[field] = '';
  }

  this.setState(newState);
}
```

** edit **

To make it clearer if I add another multidimensional object to the state I will need to include another `if statement`

```js
for (const field of Object.keys(this.state)) {
  if (field == 'reset') {
    // ...
  }

  if (field == 'extra') {
    // ...
  }

  newState[field] = '';
}
```

Ideally what I need is a copy of `this.state` before its updated then just restore the copy which has the default parameters `this.setState(copy)`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by 'nested', but here are a couple of suggestions:

```
reset() {
  let newState = {};

  for (const field of Object.keys(this.state)) {
    if (field == 'result') {
      newState.result = {
          ratio: 0,
          style: '',
      };
    }else{
        newState[field] = '';
    }
  }

  this.setState(newState);
}
```

Looping this way you avoid triggering multiple renders since you only call `setState` once.

*Edit*: If you want to avoid checking for fields with known names, you can just access those directly. 'Wrap' all your inputs in a new entry in the state, and just loop through that one:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    inputs:{
        input1: '',
        input2: '',
        input3: '',
        input4: '',
    }, 
    result: {
      'ratio': 0,
      'style': '',
    },
    extra = {
        extraKey: 1,
    }
  }
}

reset() {
  let newState = {};
  newState.result = {ratio: 0, style: ''};
  newState.extra = // ...
  newState.inputs = {};

  for (const field of Object.keys(this.state.inputs)) {
    newState.inputs[field] = '';
  }

  this.setState(newState);
}
```

It is a bit cumbersome to use a loop to update the keys in an object, but I cannot think of a simpler solution when the key names are not known in advance.

Comment: thanks for the change on avoiding multiple renders, I like it. I am still stuck on if there is away to avoid the if block though and have updated my question to make it clearer hopefully.